# Jquery ajax to vanila

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm at a very early stage of javascript and still trying to wrap my head around AJAX requests.

The page I'm using my script on seems to not like jQuery too much because it fails to load properly most of the time when the script is active therefore I'm trying to translate everything to vanilla JS.

The only thing I'm having troubles with is this ajax request. Any input will be much appreciated.

```js
var $form = $('form#test-form')
$('#submit-form').on('click', function() {
  function Send() {
    var jqxhr = $.ajax({
      url: 'url',
      mode: 'no-cors',
      method: "GET",
      dataType: "jsonp",
      data: $form.serializeObject()
    }).done(
      console.log("Success!")
    );
  }
  Send()
})
```

Comment: The modern JS equivalent to `$.ajax()` is [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). However, note that there is no equivalent of `serializeObject()` in JS, so you'll need to write that yourself. In addition, jQuery AJAX has no `mode` property, so I'm not sure what purpose that is expected to solve. If you're doing this in an attempt to work around a CORS problem, then it won't work.

Comment: Thanks Rory, just for the record the function does work as ugly as it looks. I did write the serializeObject myself and I think I added the mode because some error suggested it but what really fixed the CORS issue was changing the dataType to jsonp.
I guess I have to go learn about fetch now. All the best